# jQuery: Only substract 1 after adding 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I do this in jQuery. I already have a script that can add 1 after clicking a button. But I also want something that should substract 1 if I click on the button again, and return the button to its original state.

Here's my current jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#addMe").one('click',function(){
        var counter = parseInt($("#hiddenVal").val());

        counter++;

        $("#hiddenVal").val(counter);
        $("#theCount").text(counter);
        $("#addMe").toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```

Here's my live js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jehzlau/7hv2eyv0/

Right now, it adds 1 after I click it. The button should only be clickable once to add + 1. And the color of the button will change. That's the first one that I'm trying to achieve, and it's already working.

The only problem I have now is to revert the changes after clicking it again.

For example, if you click on the button, it's now blue and the heart is black, and the number is 2. What I want is if you click it again, the button will become green again by default, the heart to white, and the number 2 to 1. I just want to reverse what happened in the second click. Then if I click on it again (3rd click), it will go back to 2, then the button will be blue, and the heart will be black again. And if I click on it again (4th click), it will revert again. And so on... and so forth...

That's all I want to do, but I can't do it. I hope someone here can point me to the right direction. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do it this way. See if active class exist and then increment/decrement counter based on it:

```
       $("#addMe").on('click',function(){
            var counter = parseInt($("#hiddenVal").val());
            if($(this).hasClass('active'))
                counter--;
            else
                counter++;
            $("#hiddenVal").val(counter);
            $("#theCount").text(counter);
            $("#addMe").toggleClass('active');
        });
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/manantwar/p3bs9g36/)**

Comment: This also worked. The above also worked. Now I don't know what's better. Anyway, both worked. Thanks Milind. :D

Comment: Got it, this is exactly what I'm looking for. Even if it's 999 or any amount, it will add 1 in the first click, and subtract 1 in the next click. Nice. Thanks again Milind Anantwar!

Comment: @jehzlau: yup. that depends. if it is for 1 and 2 then rohans solution is great. if you want the logic to work for all values,then mine.

Comment: I'll be using your solution, because I'll implement this in a magento site with different values inside "thecount" ID. Thanks again Milind Anantwar! :D

Comment: It greatly helped and saved me hundreds of working hours trying to figure this out myself. Glad stackoverflow exists and expert people like you who are willing to share what they know are active in stackoverlow, sharing their knowledge for free for newbie coders like me. :D

Comment: @jehzlau: it is all give and take. See you around. :D

Comment: Yeah see you around. I hope you're still here in my next jquery problems to come. Hahaha :D

Answer (score 3):

Try to use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on) not [one()](http://api.jquery.com/one) like,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#addMe").on('click', function () { // use on instead of one
        var counter = parseInt($("#hiddenVal").val());
        $(this).hasClass('active') ? 1 : 2;// toggle text 1,2
        $("#hiddenVal").val(counter);
        $("#theCount").text(counter);
        $("#addMe").toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/7hv2eyv0/13/)

If you want to `add 1` and `subtract 1` from any hiddenVal then, you can change it like,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#addMe").on('click', function () { // use on instead of one
        var counter = parseInt($("#hiddenVal").val());

        // change the line where counter initialization takes place like
        $(this).hasClass('active') ? counter-- : counter++ ;

        $("#hiddenVal").val(counter);
        $("#theCount").text(counter);
        $("#addMe").toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```

Comment: Wow! That was fast! This worked. You're a true jquery master. :D

Comment: but if the number is different, it will still show 1 and 2. For example, there's 999 in "theCount" ID. But thanks for the answer it still worked. :D

Comment: If it is `999` then it would return 2 as `counter==2` will return false.

Comment: Hi Rohan, thanks for the re-written code. :D I tried it and it works. Thank you so much. :D

Answer (score 0):

If you do not really want to count but just toggle, use a global variable and just toggle:

```
var counter = false;
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#addMe").click(function(){
            counter = !counter;
            $("#hiddenVal").val(counter);
            $("#theCount").text(counter);
            $("#addMe").toggleClass('active');
        });
    });
```

You can also drop the hidden element in your form.

Comment: I would like to count, because it will be implemented as a wishlist functionality in a magento site. @Milind Anantwar answer is exactly what I'm trying to achieve. Thanks Sir Tobi for the suggestion. :D